# Concatenate words in lex with as few allocation as possible

Tags: c, lex

During the lexical parsing of a source file test.c, say it to be

> ...
>   // pragma ... one two ...
>   ...

I need to get some info from this comment. If yytext currently points to "one", I want to concatenate "one" and "two".
Can I do it this way to avoid allocating memory for `p1`?

```
char* p1 = yytext; // yytext points to "one"
yytext += strlen(yytext)+1; // yytext now points to "two"
...
char* p = strcat(p1, yytext); // p should points to "onetwo"
```

This works fine for my current test. But I'm afraid `p1` may point to illegal memory after yytext changed.

Comment: Skipping over a token with `yytext += strlen(yytext)+1` is almost certainly illegal. Using `strcat` straight into former `yytext` probably causes UB as well. Don't write into variables provided by lex; allocate your own.

Comment: This is a bit too few information to give a good answer, but usually, you should try to configure your lexer in a way that "one two" would be scanned as _one_ token, instead of reading two tokens and concatenate them. Isn't that possible in your case?

Comment: I refreshed my description, please have a look.@Ctx @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the `yymore()` lex action.

Calling `yymore()` in a (f)lex action causes the current token to be retained so that the match of the next pattern is effectively concatenated to the current token. There are examples in the flex manual which illustrate some of the uses.

In a (f)lex action, you are free to modify any byte in the token string pointed to by `yytext` but you must not modify (and should not reference) any bytes in the (f)lex buffer in which that string is contained. That means that you should not modify the token's NUL terminator, because the effect would be to extend the token beyond its length into the "rest" of the buffer, which might not exist. (In flex, the buffer happens to be terminated with two NUL bytes, so there is a "rest" of the buffer, but that is not the case with other lex implementations so you could create a buffer overrun by overwriting the NUL terminator.)